# Replace string of text javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to replace a string of text for another string of text here is my code plus js fiddle

### HTML

```
<div class="label">Rating:</div>
<div class="data rating">****</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var str=document.getElementsByClassName("data" ,"raiting").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(/\*/g,"star");
document.getElementsByClassName("data", "raiting").innerHTML=n;
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/sgGQz/1/

Comment: `getElements` means you may have several elements, they are in a 0 indexed array. Choose one before accessing `innerHtml`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) method returns, as its name suggests, a collection ([HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) of elements, not a single one -even if there's just a single element with the given classname(s) in DOM.

You need to go through each of them in order to make such a replacement. For example:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("data rating");
for (var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\*/g, 'star');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A99q9/).

Alternatively, if you know for sure that there should be only a single element, you can assign it directly:

```
var elementToAdjust = document.getElementsByClassName("data rating")[0];
// ...
```

Comment: `raiting` is going to break your code.  Just a simple spelling error in the original post.  Also multiple classes passed to `getElementsByClassName` are specified as one argument that has space delimited class names.  The fiddle works only because the second argument `raiting` passed to `getElementsByClassName` is ignored.

Comment: In the JS its `raiting` but in the HTML its `rating`

Comment: @KevinBowersox Ah yes, of course; it gets unnoticed because of how `className` params are specified. Thanks again. )

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one occurrence of the element this will work:

```
var str=document.getElementsByClassName("data rating")[0].innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(/\*/g,"star");
document.getElementsByClassName("data rating")[0].innerHTML=n;
```

If multiple `data rating` elements exist use:

```
    var elems =document.getElementsByClassName("data rating");
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
        elems[i].innerHTML = elems[i].innerHTML.replace(/\*/g,"star");
    }
```

Both method correct some flaws in the original code.

First, rating was misspelled in the argument passed to `getElementsByClassName`.  Second, `getElementsByClassName()` uses class names delimited by spaces to select elements with multiple classes, instead of multiple arguments.  Get `elementsByClassName` returns an array of elements which must be iterated through.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/sgGQz/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check again for [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName),It returns node-List, so you can do like this and You can loop through then after each element and set your value

```
var str=document.getElementsByClassName("data" ,"raiting")[0].innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(/\*/g,"star");
document.getElementsByClassName("data", "raiting")[0].innerHTML=n;
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sgGQz/4/) as you have only one occurance