# Replacing <> arrows with HTML using only plain javascript

Tags: javascript

## Question

How can I replace a `<` with an anchor as an HTML wrapper?

### Background

I am getting a JSON value with a Twitter user's name as something like 

`<jgallardo949>`

Since i don't want that printed to the page:

- i want to replace the `<` with `<a
  href="twitter.com/{{data.author}}">`
- and the `>` with `</a>`
- The end result in the code will be `<a
  href="twitter.com/jgallardo949">jgallardo949</a>`
- The end result on the page will just be: jgallardo949

I referenced other similar questions that I was able to find here and elsewhere. I got a start with the answers on [Replace string of text javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824371/replace-string-of-text-javascript)

My followup practice worked. But specifically the `>` symbol is having a challenge, or i am missing something?

### Code

The top two work, the last one does not

#### HTML

```
<div class="label">With Profits Financial Strength:</div>
<div class="data rating">****</div>
<div class="data2 thing">+</div>
<div class="author twitter"> > </div>
```

#### JS

```
var str=document.getElementsByClassName("data" ,"raiting")[0].innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(/\*/g,"star");
document.getElementsByClassName("data", "raiting")[0].innerHTML=n;



var str2=document.getElementsByClassName("data2" ,"thing")[0].innerHTML; 
var n2=str2.replace(/\+/g,"<h1>moon</h1>");
document.getElementsByClassName("data2", "thing")[0].innerHTML=n2;


var str3=document.getElementsByClassName("author" ,"twitter")[0].innerHTML; 
var n2=str3.replace(/\>/g,"<h1>moon3</h1>");
document.getElementsByClassName("author", "twitter")[0].innerHTML=n2;
```

[image]

Comment: Is the Twitter username always prefixed with exactly 1 `<` and suffixed with exactly 1 `>`? Or is this username an exception?

Comment: Yes @Peter, the username would be displayed in the format i listed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `>` in HTML gets returned as `&gt;` so doing like this `(\>|&gt;)` and it will find both.

```
var n2=str3.replace(/(\>|&gt;)/g,"<h1>moon3</h1>");
```

Stack snippet

```js
var str=document.getElementsByClassName("data" ,"raiting")[0].innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace(/\*/g,"star");
document.getElementsByClassName("data", "raiting")[0].innerHTML=n;



var str2=document.getElementsByClassName("data2" ,"thing")[0].innerHTML; 
var n2=str2.replace(/\+/g,"<h1>moon</h1>");
document.getElementsByClassName("data2", "thing")[0].innerHTML=n2;


var str3=document.getElementsByClassName("author" ,"twitter")[0].innerHTML; 
var n2=str3.replace(/(\>|&gt;)/g,"<h1>moon3</h1>");
document.getElementsByClassName("author", "twitter")[0].innerHTML=n2;
```

```html
<div class="label">With Profits Financial Strength:</div>
<div class="data rating">****</div>
<div class="data2 thing">+</div>
<div class="author twitter"> > </div>
```

Comment: This does absolutely answer my question, thank you. The problem is that I did not ask the right question since I also need to escape some values and perhaps not do `innerHTML`.

Comment: @JGallardo Based on how you will inject, not using `innerHTML` might inject a HTML element like this: http://jsfiddle.net/by0z3ujn/ ... and what about escape some values, what you mean to do with that?

Comment: Also wondering about targeting the character inside of a string. By itself, the `>` is wrapped just fine. But when something like `<name>` is returned, i am getting `moon3 moon3` so looks like the middle portion (name) is not displayed at all, and either left or right (less-than greater-than) is subject to the change.

Comment: @JGallardo If you make me a jsfiddle, similar to my answer code sample, showing that `<name>` issue, I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks, in the example, i am now just trying to do a simple wrap with an `<h1>` http://jsfiddle.net/L6ay70sp/

Comment: @JGallardo As you can see in the first alert (in the fiddle linked to later in this comment), having a non-closed tag like `<name>`, the browser (at least Chrome) assumed its being an actual HTML element, and automatically gives it a close tag so it becomes `<name></name>`. That means that your initial replace code won't work. In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qdmj7t1h/ I show a simple fix where I grab its `tagName`, though whether that will work cross browser I can't say.

Comment: @JGallardo Another would be a Regex and capture the text inside start tags, like this http://jsfiddle.net/u3bemfrq/ though which is better of these two is up to you, but hopefully I showed/explained something that can be useful.

Comment: if you have a moment if you could see my followup question which presents the other challenges faced and a partial proposed soltuion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201624/extracting-a-string-between-a-known-symbols-and-assigning-it-as-a-reusable-varia

Comment: @JGallardo I did...and posted an answer, though it could have been added to my answer here, as they are pretty much the same.