# Extracting a string between a known symbols and assigning it as a reusable variable using only javascript

Tags: javascript

### what I am trying to do

- I need to get all of the twitter usernames from a returned JSON value, currently being returned inside arrows, example would be `<jgallardo949>`
- Assign those values as a variables
- append that variable to a url from twitter.com
- Take the string before the twitter username and assign that as a value
- Create a new variable with the combination of other generated variables and wrap it in desired HTML
- Display the desired new HTML inside of a div
- Do this for every instance of strings generated inside of any div with a class of `author`

---

### Sample JSON

```
"contributed_by":"Sasha <SashaMasondeCaires>"
```

### Desired HTML output

```
Sasha <a href="https://www.twitter.com/SashaMasondeCaires">@SashaMasondeCaires</a>
```

---

### Conceptual solution

Since it is currently returning in that format, `name <twitter username>` then what I want to do is replace `<` with `<a href="https://www.twitter.com/` and `>` with `</a>`, but what then should i do with the name, perhaps make that a variable so that it would be something like

```
//To get the string inside the <>
var authTw = document.getElementsByClassName("author")[0].innerHTML;
//wrapping solution needs work
var twUsername = "<span>@" + authTw.match(/\<([a-z]*)\>/)[1] + "</span>"
document.getElementsByClassName("author")[0].innerHTML=twUsername;

var authorName = // I need to get the string before the < symbol
var contributorInfo = authorName + '<a href="https://twitter.com/' + twUsername + '">' + twUsername + '</a>';
```

And then I need to write the resulting `contributorInfo` in the div with the class `.author`

---

## Current code

### HTML

```
<div class="author">{{ beer.contributor }}</div>
```

### JS Babel - Axios

```
contributor: api.contributed_by,
```

### API Endpoint

```
https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/random
```

### JSON - sample

```
[{
  "id": 126,
  "name": "Jet Black Heart",
  "tagline": "Oatmeal Milk Stout. Dark. Roasty. Velvety.",
  "first_brewed": "01/2016",
  "description": "Good things come to those who wait. This smooth and roasty oatmeal milk stout won our 2015 Prototype Challenge at a canter. Roasty coffee and chocolate lead to a decadent, full-bodied richness of near uncharted depths with a velvet mouthfeel from the addition of oatmeal and a touch of wheat. This is complemented at every turn by the Magnum and Sorachi Ace hops, with the latter bringing an intensity of smooth vanilla and dark berry fruit on the long, rewarding finish.",
  "image_url": "https://images.punkapi.com/v2/126.png",
  "abv": 4.7,
  "ibu": 45,
  "target_fg": 1019,
  "target_og": 1055,
  "ebc": 200,
  "srm": 100,
  "ph": 4.4,
  "attenuation_level": 70,
  "volume": {
    "value": 20,
    "unit": "liters"
  },
  "boil_volume": {
    "value": 25,
    "unit": "liters"
  },
  "method": {
    "mash_temp": [{
      "temp": {
        "value": 65,
        "unit": "celsius"
      },
      "duration": 75
    }],
    "fermentation": {
      "temp": {
        "value": 19,
        "unit": "celsius"
      }
    },
    "twist": null
  },
  "ingredients": {
    "malt": [{
      "name": "Pale Ale",
      "amount": {
        "value": 2.75,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Wheat",
      "amount": {
        "value": 0.25,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Dark Crystal",
      "amount": {
        "value": 0.19,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Brown",
      "amount": {
        "value": 0.38,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Black",
      "amount": {
        "value": 0.19,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Carafa Special Malt Type 1",
      "amount": {
        "value": 0.19,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Flaked Oats",
      "amount": {
        "value": 0.38,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Crystal 150",
      "amount": {
        "value": 0.25,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }, {
      "name": "Lactose",
      "amount": {
        "value": 0.38,
        "unit": "kilograms"
      }
    }],
    "hops": [{
      "name": "Magnum",
      "amount": {
        "value": 12.5,
        "unit": "grams"
      },
      "add": "start",
      "attribute": "bitter"
    }, {
      "name": "Sorachi Ace",
      "amount": {
        "value": 6.3,
        "unit": "grams"
      },
      "add": "middle",
      "attribute": "flavour"
    }],
    "yeast": "Wyeast 1056 - American Ale™"
  },
  "food_pairing": ["Oyster beignets", "Beef shin stew", "A Shakin' jesse"],
  "brewers_tips": "There's a lot of speciality malt in the mash. Make sure you take the run off nice and steady – increase the flow too much and pull in the bed at your peril.",
  "contributed_by": "Sasha <SashaMasondeCaires>"
}]
```

---

### Edit 1

One answer partially helped, and this is [my current pen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/QxXPYW)

Since I am writing strings multiple times to divs with a class of `author`

#### HTML example

```
<div class="author">Joe <crabshack></div>
<div class="author">juan <tacotruck></div>
<div class="author">Jesse <Canvas></div>
```

#### Current attempted JS

```
var user = document.getElementsByClassName('author').innerHTML;

var matches = user.match(/(.*)\s\<(.*)\>/);
var output = `${matches[1]} <a href="https://www.twitter.com/${matches[2]}" target="_blank">@${matches[2]}</a>`;

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

The part that is the problem is `var user = document.getElementsByClassName('author').innerHTML;`

---

### Edit 3

When i tried

```
var user = document.querySelector(".author").innerHTML;
```

it was only giving me the first of that class, but i need to get all the values.

Comment: So when you say _"Since it is currently returning in that format, `name <twitter username>`"_, what does that actually mean?...what is it that returns that format? ... as I showed in a previous comment/answer how custom HTML elements get returned, your `name <twitter username>` appears to not come from a HTML document, and if so, then you can use the replacement suggested in the previous given answer.

Comment: did you try capturing it with a simple regex along the lines of `/^(.*)\<([a-z]*)\>/` (that way the regex match should return 2 groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how-to using javascript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `${variable}` and a Regex `/(.*)\s\<([a-z]*)\>/`.

Stack snippet

```js
var user = "Sasha <SashaMasondeCaires>";
var matches = user.match(/(.*)\s\<(.*)\>/);
var output = `${matches[1]} <a href="https://www.twitter.com/${matches[2]}">@${matches[2]}</a>`;

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

---

Updated based on a comment/jsfiddle demo

Here is an updated version of your demo code

```js
var user = document.getElementsByClassName('author');
for (var i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {

  var matches = user[i].innerHTML.match(/(.*)\s\<([a-z]*)\>/);

  var output = `${matches[1]} <a href="https://www.twitter.com/${matches[2]}" target="_blank">@${matches[2]}</a><br>`;

  document.body.innerHTML += output;

}
```

```css
.author {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="author">Joe <crabshack></div>
<div class="author">juan <tacotruck></div>
<div class="author">Joe <Canvas></div>
<div id="author">Juan Gallardo <JGallardo949></div>
```

Comment: This does work as is, but because I have to target multiple strings on a page, i tried this `var user = document.getElementsByClassName('author').innerHTML;` but having an issue. here is my pen, https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/QxXPYW

Comment: When i tried `var user = document.querySelector(".author").innerHTML;` i only got the first value and nothing else showed in the other divs with values

Comment: @JGallardo I edited my answer with an updated version of your fiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest to parse this is just:

```
const [name, twitter] = input.split(">")[0].split("<").map(str => str.trim());

return `${name} <a href="twitter.com/${twitter}" >@${twitter}</a>`;
```

Comment: This should make sense to most, but I seem to be missing some steps. Like targeting only inside of a div with a certain class

Comment: @JGallardo These 2 answers do not take into account what I showed in the comments at your previous question, they only show how to extract and inject the very same, into a string.